# How to set flow variables from Process builder

Tags: process-builder, visual-workflow

I'm trying to launch one flow from process builder, but on selecting that flow from process builder I'm not able to set the flow variables.

Bascially set flow variable option is not coming for me in Process Builder.

Comment: Is the variable in the flow set as Input only or Input/Output?, otherwise it is not available externally.

Comment: currently it is private, that means I need to make it Input??

Comment: Yes, make it input, make that version of the flow active and it will be visible to process builder. Remember that you would need to exit process builder and go back in to edit to see the flow changes.

Comment: If my flow is sending an email after 10 days where can I check that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As dave said, make your variable as input or input/out.

As far as checking where the time-based processes are queued up for flows, on the flow page, where you view all your flows, go to the very bottom.
[image]